# C# xUnit Test listeners

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, xunit, xunit.net

I'm building a selenium test framework based on .Net Core and the team decided to go with xUnit. All's well and good everything has been going ok but for a while now, we've been trying to replicate the functionality of Java TestNG listeners without much luck.

I've been digging around the xunit git repo and found a few instances where some  interfaces such `ITestListener` have been used. After digging deeper, I found that these listeners are from a package called `TestDriven.Framework` and I wanted to know exactly how would I use a test listener created using those interfaces?

So far this is my simple test listener that should write something when the test fails:

```
public class Listener
{
    readonly int totalTests;

    public Listener(ITestListener listener, int totalTests)
    {
        this.totalTests = totalTests;
        TestListener = listener;
        TestRunState = TestRunState.NoTests;
    }

    public ITestListener TestListener { get; private set; }
    public TestRunState TestRunState { get; set; }

    public void onTestFail(ITestFailed args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args.Messages);
    }

}
```

Now, I know you can do this inside a tear down hook but remember, this is just a simple example and what I have in mind is something more complex. So to be precise, where/how exactly would I register the test to use this listener? In Java TestNg I would have `@Listeners` but in C# I'm not too sure.

**Edit 1** so the example worked and managed to add it to my own project structure but when I try to use this

```
    class TestPassed : TestResultMessage, ITestPassed
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="TestPassed"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public TestPassed(ITest test, decimal executionTime, string output)
        : base(test, executionTime, output) {
        Console.WriteLine("Execution time was an awesome " + executionTime);
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble registering this one, or if i'm even registering it right. As far as the examples go, I have found the actual message sinks but also found the actual test status data which i'm not exactly sure how to use.

Comment: So your goal in Edit 1 is to listen for the "Test Passed" message? I'll update my answer to demonstrate...

Comment: yeah, my overall goal is to be able to do something based on different test statuses and test events. Using your example I can abstract the crude if/else method and implement a better way. If you want you can update the example for future people with a better example showing more test statuses such as passed, skipped, failed, started, finished and whatnot. the general example is the same  using the interfaces `ITestFailed` `ITestSkipped` and so on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't worked with TestNG, but I did some quick reading and I *think* I see what you're after.

To demonstrate, I've created a very basic proof-of-concept implementation of the xUnit [`IMessageSink`](https://github.com/xunit/abstractions.xunit/blob/master/src/xunit.abstractions/Messages/BaseInterfaces/IMessageSink.cs) interface.

```cs
public class MyMessageSink : IMessageSink
{
    public bool OnMessage(IMessageSinkMessage message)
    {
        // Do what you want to in response to events here.
        // 
        // Each event has a corresponding implementation of IMessageSinkMessage.
        // See examples here: https://github.com/xunit/abstractions.xunit/tree/master/src/xunit.abstractions/Messages
        if (message is ITestPassed)
        {
            // Beware that this message won't actually appear in the Visual Studio Test Output console.
            // It's just here as an example. You can set a breakpoint to see that the line is hit.
            Console.WriteLine("Execution time was an awesome " + ((ITestPassed)message).ExecutionTime);
        }

        // Return `false` if you want to interrupt test execution.
        return true;
    }
}
```

The sink is then registered via an [`IRunnerReporter`](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/master/src/xunit.runner.utility/Extensibility/IRunnerReporter.cs):

```cs
public class MyRunnerReporter : IRunnerReporter
{
    public string Description => "My custom runner reporter";

    // Hard-coding `true` means this reporter will always be enabled.
    //
    // You can also implement logic to conditional enable/disable the reporter.
    // Most reporters based this decision on an environment variable.
    // Eg: https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/cbf28f6d911747fc2bcd64b6f57663aecac91a4c/src/xunit.runner.reporters/TeamCityReporter.cs#L11
    public bool IsEnvironmentallyEnabled => true;
        
    public string RunnerSwitch => "mycustomrunnerreporter";

    public IMessageSink CreateMessageHandler(IRunnerLogger logger)
    {
        return new MyMessageSink();
    }
}
```

To use my example code, just copy the classes into your test project (you'll also need to add a reference to the `xunit.runner.utility` NuGet package). The xUnit framework will automagically discover the `IRunnerReporter`--no need to explicitly register anything.

If this seems like it's headed in the right direction, you can find a lot more info in the xUnit source code. All of the interfaces involved are well-documented. There are a few existing implementations in the [xunit.runner.reporters namespace](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/tree/master/src/xunit.runner.reporters). [AssemblyRunner.cs](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/cbf28f6d911747fc2bcd64b6f57663aecac91a4c/src/xunit.runner.utility/Runners/AssemblyRunner.cs#L306:L371) also demonstrates one possible method for dispatching the different event types to individual handlers.

### Edit 1

I've updated the implementation of `MyMessageSink` (above) to demonstrate how you might listen for an `ITestPassed` message. I also updated the link embedded in that code snippet--the previous link was to implementations, but we should really use these abstractions.

The `if (message is IMessageType)` pattern is pretty crude, and won't scale well if you want to listen for many different message types. Since I don't know your needs, I just went with the simplest thing that could possibly work--hopefully it's enough that you can improve/extend it to fit your needs.

Comment: so i basically just run the tests and it will discover the message sink automatically?

Comment: Yep. I don't know the exact rules for where the `IRunnerReporter` can be, but I put mine in the root of the test project and it Just Worked.

Comment: sorry, accidently edited your answer instead of my question. Ignore the edit

Comment: Were you ever able to have this work with classic .net? The same project targeting net461 won't load the IRunnerReporter.

Comment: @J.D.Cain I don't remember exactly what .NET Version(s) I tested this against--it's been over a year since I worked on it. I'm not aware of anything that would prevent this from working on .NET 4.6. You might find answers in the source code for the [console](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/63b1c8586d2bec9cc5936c501e5b8c05320cc53b/src/xunit.console/ConsoleRunner.cs#L125:L173) or [msbuild](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/63b1c8586d2bec9cc5936c501e5b8c05320cc53b/src/xunit.runner.msbuild/xunit.cs#L356-L398) test runners. If you need more help, I recommend a new question with code samples.

Comment: @xander You've got a great answer here that I think I'll be able to use.  But I lost you on this statement: "All of the interfaces involved are well-documented."  The web site https://xunit.net has been pretty good getting me started with XUnit, but when trying to find answers to questions like this, I'm not able to find any API documentation online, nor is there any Wiki page on https://github.com/xunit/xunit.  I would think that documentation in the code would be run through a documentation generation tool and posted online somewhere.  What am I missing?

Comment: I was referring to the XML comments included in the source code. Visual Studio renders them as tool tips and also displays them in the decompiled code after "F12"-ing into a method/class/interface definition. This is just my interpretation, but it seems the xUnit maintainers have chosen to document primarily intent online and to document implementation details only in code. It saves them a lot of overhead maintaining the website while also ensuring that we're always looking at the documentation for the exact version of the code we're running.

Comment: It seems to me auto-discovery will work only when xunit runner is in place. When tests are run from Rider for example the IRunnerReporter will be ignored.. Anybody found a way to make this work with Rider?

Comment: @vmachacek Rider currently does not support custom IRunnerReporter discovery. You can vote on that feature here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-488382/Load-custom-reporter-dll